# IIS-based Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, visual-studio-2019

I have created an ASP.NET Web Application in Visual Studio Community 2019. I am trying to deploy a web service in IIS but I keep getting the 404 Not Found error. The application pool in the IIS manager looks like this

[image]

I create a connection

[image]

and then publish the application but I get this error

[image]

The .NET Framework is 4.7.2
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per your screen shot application is hosted with virtual directory Webapp.
URL Should be http://Localhost/webapp/webservice1.asmx

Answer (score 0):

First change url to http://Localhost/webapp/webservice1.asmx. Then check [Mapping to an ASMX service using routing in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764925/mapping-to-an-asmx-service-using-routing-in-asp-net-mvc/16833682) for solving the mapping problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest publishing the site to the folder. Then create a new site in IIS Manager and show its physical path to that folder. Give your site some path like localhost:3600. Then when you open that path in the browser and search http://localhost:3600/WebService1.asmx, it will definitely work(at least it worked for me)